# How to auto expand text-area upwards?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, chat

I have an auto expanding text area on card-footer. https://jsfiddle.net/6f9a52we/

Instead of expanding it downwards, Can i make it expand upwards? So as it expands upwards, the card-body should shrink. As we see in Gmail chat.

I tried using **position: absolute; and bottom:0px;**. In that case, Expanding upwards is working perfectly, But the expanding text-area is covering the texts in card-body due to absolute position. Any Ideas please without using **position:absolute** ?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        card body line 1<br>
        card body line 2<br>
        card body line 3<br>
        card body line 4<br>
        card body line 5
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <textarea id="myTextArea" placeholder="type here"></textarea>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
$(function() {
  $('#myTextArea').on('input keyup paste', function() {
    var $el = $(this),
        offset = $el.innerHeight() - $el.height();

    if ($el.innerHeight() < this.scrollHeight) {
      // Grow the field if scroll height is smaller
      $el.height(this.scrollHeight - offset);
    } else {
      // Shrink the field and then re-set it to the scroll height in case it needs to shrink
      $el.height(1);
      $el.height(this.scrollHeight - offset);
    }
  });
});
```

```
  .card{
        text-align: center;
        width: 50%;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .card-body{
        overflow-y: auto;
        height: 150px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add max height to your class card.

```
  .card{
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    max-height: 250px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Woww man !! That's brilliant ! I've been trying to figure this out for so long lol. Thanks :) Perfect